# Node.js tracing options

Tags: node.js

Node.js 7 has command-line switches `--trace-events-enabled` & `--trace-event-categories` that look promising for debugging simple problems, but the [`tracing` documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/tracing.html) is rather sparse.

I don't see for example a list of what trace event categories may be specified on the command line or API level docs.  Perhaps there is a command switch to display categories.   Is there a trace category for tracing *module loading* which could be used in *Error: Cannot find module* messages?

Does Node 6 have anything similar from the module load trace standpoint?

Comment: I believe the only categories available by default are V8 and Node. One can add additional custom categories though I am yet to find out how. Then you go to chrome://tracing in Google Chrome, for example, to view the log files it generates.